# Different Phoenix Endpoints. e.g. Helloweb v Hello.Web

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When creating a new Phoenix 1.3 project, I notice that my endpoint in `config/prod.exs` is `Bia.Web.Endpoint`.  When looking at the Phoenix Hex Docs, I see they reference `Helloweb.Endpoint`.  I'm assuming the latter format should be the default, because when I generate a context with `mix phx.gen.html` I get the compile error below, highlighting it cannot find module `Biaweb`. I can go into the controller and rename `Biaweb` to `Bia.Web`, and it then resolves, but I just run into a host of further issues.

```
== Compilation error on file lib/bia_web/controllers/user_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/bia_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:2: module BiaWeb is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    lib/bia_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:2: BiaWeb.UserController (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

What's going on here? What should be the correct format.

Comment: Which version of `phx.new` do you have installed? IIRC 1.3 final release should be generating `BiaWeb.Endpoint`. Maybe you have some 1.3-rc version installed?

Comment: Have a strong suspicion I have the 1.3rc. I'll check when I get back to that machine later.

Comment: To add to what @dogbert said:

1.) Check your version of phoenix via `mix phx.new --version`
2.) Double check your version of Elixir as well with `elixir --version`
3.) Post the exact command line you used to create the new Phoenix project.

Comment: @Dogbert - completely right.  I had 1.3-rc installed.  Updated to v1.3 and all is well.  Do you want to repost as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix had a brief period before 1.3 final version where it generated modules in the format `MyApp.Web` instead of `MyAppWeb`. You must have `phx.new` from version `1.3-rc` installed on your system. Once you upgrade that by running the command below, it should generate the correct module names:

```
$ mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez
```

Comment: This post is pretty high in Google when searching `Phoenix MyApp.Web vs MyAppWeb`. Even on Chris's own presentation it used to be Web as a namespace, not suffix. Would be great if someone found a link to the justification for this change. I couldn't find it, but I'm sure it's buried somewhere in mailing lists or issues.